# Is seeing high CPU utilization always bad?

Tags: web-applications, performance-testing

Let's take couple of scenarios here:

1. I have a web application which reaches a CPU of 90% whenever I make couple of requests to a specific end point.
2. I am load testing my other web application where I see a throughput of 100,000 requests/second. Here also I see a CPU of 90%.

In scenario #1, I can understand that this is pretty bad, but how should one decide if this is good/bad. I mean 100,000 requests is pretty huge, so how does one decide if the utilization is bad?

Comment: You need to compare this to your expected usage levels, for instance, is 100.000 a lot more than you expect and want to scale for? Is it at the lower bound? What if it grows by 10%? 20%

Comment: Thanks @LasseVågsætherKarlsen. I _think_ I get what you are saying. If let's say my expected usage level is 50,000 rps and the CPU is around 50-60% then I can be happy to know that my server can peak to 100,000 with a 90% CPU usage. In this give scenario, then its safe to say that CPU utilization is not bad?

Comment: In that scenario, that would be my thought as well. In the other scenario, where just "a couple of requests" peak to 90% you have nothing to go on, even just 1 extra request, assuming the requests evently consume cpu, will create some kind of problem.

Comment: It is also important that you design your application with scaling in mind for these scenarios, so that when the day comes when it closes in on 100% under normal load, peak load creating a problem, you want to be in a position where scaling is a matter of spinning up more servers/containers/whatever, instead of having to *then* start redesigning your application.

Comment: Thanks again. You can make your comments as answer and I will accept it.